# How to get submitted data from wordpress forminator form after sumission?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get submitted data from forminator form as soon as user submit and data inserted into database. I want to get the submitted data and store into different db table.
I have tried below hooks, but no luck -

1. forminator_form_after_save_entry
2. forminator_custom_form_after_handle_submit
3. forminator_custom_form_submit_before_set_fields

can you guys help me

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one?

```
add_filter('forminator_custom_form_submit_field_data', 'custom_form_submit', 11, 2);
function custom_form_submit($field_data_array, $form_id){
   //Todo: some code
   return $field_data_array;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).